# Failing to retrieve user after passport authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

If authentication succeeds, then the user is redirected to the "/profile" route, as the following code indicates.

```
app.get(
        "/auth/google/callback",
        passport.authenticate("google", { successRedirect: "/profile", failureRedirect: "/failure" })
)
```

The route for the profile page looks like this.

```
app.get("/profile", function(req, res) {

    console.log("Attempting to render profile")
    console.log("USER: " + req.user)

    res.render("profile.jade", {
        user: req.user
    })
})
```

In the console, when running the program I see "Attempting to render profile" and then it shows the user object but then in the browser, it seems as if it loads eternally. It gets stuck on the res.render("profile.jade", ... etc.

If I close the page loading, right after I close it the console says "GET /profile - - ms - -"

My passport configuration file, using Google Oauth2 and MySQL looks like this. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6265a7779154a087b833

Comment: I honestly don't know too much about this, but do you not want to call `res.send` like what's done [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send)?

Comment: Do you have your `app.js` or something similar to look at...I wonder if some middleware or something isn't loading right?  When you `console.log(req)` the whole request object, do you get anything?

Comment: Now it is saying "USER: [object Object]" and then loading forever. Same code. Let me send my app.js

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/634b706108784de6f706

Comment: Instead of using a `+` use a `,`, like `console.log("User", req);`

Comment: When I do console.log(req) it displays it correctly in JSON in the console. I see the user information in there. So the program is apparently getting stuck on the redirect for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the fix was to pass the correct variable to the jade template

Comment: And if you take away the .jade from the `profile.jade`, what happens?

Comment: It performs the same way. Other routes that have the .jade extension work. Also if I remove the user object being fed into the render method and just do res.render('profile.jade") it still loads indefinitely. If I close the page loading, right after I close it the console says "GET /profile - - ms - -"

Comment: What in the world! I removed the console.log statements from within the route and now it loads. But it seems to be loading an ENTIRELY different page. What in the world!

Comment: And what page does it load?

Comment: The page loading differently was my fault. Apparently it wasn't loading because I was using a variable that didn't exist on the Jade page. You can edit that into your answer and I will mark it as accepted. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Cool, glad you got.  Best.

Comment: I tried to add "When you use an incorrect or nonexistent variable in a Jade template and try to render it, it does not load." and a mod denied. I think that is relevant info that probably needs to be in the answer. Because the variable being passed into Jade wasn't the issue. It was using an incorrect variable inside of the Jade template.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6265a7779154a087b833 line: 63
You didn't insert googleid to database how can you get that out

Comment: But it is getting it out... The user in req is displaying properly and the ID is being inserted into the database. See lines 70-80.

Comment: The name in the database is different than the variable name. That part works. It loads the user into req properly.